# Exchange online outbound execution order

Tags: microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

I am writing an outbound connector for exchange online but want to understand the order of execution better.

This is how I think things would happen but confirmation would be appreciated:

1. Sender sends the message
2. Message is sent to my server via my connector
   3.... Stuff happens...
3. Message is returned into exchange
4. EOP performs outbound spam checks
5. Message is Dkim signed
6. Message finally sent to recipient

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is exactly what you have said above.

Based on my knowledge, exchange online mail flow is similar to exchange 2016 mail flow progress. For more details: [Understanding the transport pipeline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/mail-flow?view=exchserver-2019#understanding-the-transport-pipeline)

But if you are in hybrid, you could refer to the article: [Transport routing in Exchange hybrid deployments](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/transport-routing)

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. I have noticed that the message is getting DKIM signed before and after the message has been sent via the connector but that's a trivial issue in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Yes, here's a blog on How DKIM Works for your reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35595.on-premises-exchange-dkim-and-dmarc-setup.aspx